# Creating multiple blog like lists using Jekyll hydeout theme

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, blogs

I'm using the [hydeout theme](https://github.com/fongandrew/hydeout) in jekyll and I am trying to have 3 sections in the side bar;

Home - A list of all posts including pagination (working already)
College - A list of all college category posts with pagination
Fun - A list of all fun category posts with pagination

So far using the theme I have the sections in the side bar and the home page is showing all posts from both categories including pagination.

However my issue is that **the category layout is only setup to show post titles** and I cannot get it to act as a full list of posts let alone include pagination.

**category.html**:

```
{% unless page.content == '' %}
  {{ content }}
{% endunless %}

<ul class="posts-list">
  {% assign category = page.category | default: page.title %}
  {% for post in site.categories[category] %}
    <li>
      <h3>
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">
          {{ post.title }}
          <small>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</small>
        </a>
      </h3>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is a link to the [hosted site](https://collegeworking.github.io/hydeout/) and the code on [github](https://github.com/collegeworking/hydeout).

I essentially want the college and fun subsections to display posts the exact same way the home page does but only posts that belong in their given category

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And ? Your site is behaving as expect. Or I don't understand your question, or your can delete it.

Comment: It may not be stated clear enough in the post - I'll bold it in the post but the issue is that if you look at the college or fun sections only post titles are shown for the categories not full posts like the home page.